# How to read exactly 4 char in c ..?

Tags: c

I want to read exactly 4 chars from the console for this I'm doing this, but it is not working as I expect it to, it reads more & less chars ..

```
    int main()
{
    char arr[4];
    scanf("%s",&arr);
    printf("%s",arr);
    return 0;
}
```

My Input to this program is this:

```
sachinjainsachin
sachinjainsachin
```

It prints the whole the char array while the size of array is `4`. I don't know why it is printing more than the size, it should to print only 4 chars i.e. **sachi**

Comment: `read more & less char`..is pretty unclear. Can you show some input/output to explain more?

Comment: Users ave very very untrustworthy! You cannot rely on them doing what you expect. Reading from terminal is hard! I suggest you read full lines rather than characters, then parse the lines inside your program: error treatment will be easier.

Comment: "sachi" are 5 chars (6 if you count the terminator `\0`)

Answer (score 6):

What you are doing is undefined behavior. The fact that it works at all is merely coincidental. What happens in this case is random and irrelevant, as its undefined. writing outside the bounds of your string array with `scanf()` will at best cause what you saw. At worst it will crash your program with a segmentation fault.

Take note that arr[4] is only good for a string with 3 characters and a terminator. Every string in C needs a `\0` as terminator at the end of it.

If you don't need a variable max length, you can do:

```c
int main (void)
{
    char str[5] = { };
    scanf("%4s", str);
    printf("%s",str);
    return 0;
}
```

Additionally, if you want to read a variable amount of characters into your string, you can do it like this:

```c
int main (void)
{
    char del[128] = { };
    char str[5] = { };
    int max = 4;
    sprintf(del, "%%%dc", max);
    scanf(del, str);
    printf("%s",str);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why is the `sprintf` needed? Why not just `scanf("%4s", str);` directly?

Comment: So you can vary the max lenght easily?

Comment: If it is not done at runtime, it is not hard to change '4' to something else.

Comment: @rozina assuming that this is the only instance of calling this. Assuming it is not done at runtime. But I added an alternative according to your suggestions.

Comment: Imo examples on stackoverflow should be simple and minimal. Its up to readers to make it more usable if they need to.

Comment: @Magisch some compilers will warn you if the format string argument of `printf`, `scanf`, etc., is not a string literal, because they cannot do any type checking on the remaining arguments in that case. (E.g., GCC tags `printf` etc. with an attribute to perform type checking on the arguments, and warns if the format string argument is not a string literal.)

Comment: @mag Just a suggestion, it is length, not lenght

Answer (score 2):

Strings in c language must be null terminated.if you want to write 4 characters,then `'\0'` must be the 5th element in the array.use it like this:

```
int main()
{
    char arr[5];
    scanf(" %4s",arr);
    printf("%s\n",arr);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to read 4 chars (but as a string), you need the changes:

1) your array size needs to be at least 5.
2) You are passing the address of an array which is of type `char(*)[]` whereas `scanf()` expects `char*` for format specifier `%s`.

To read only 4 chars, you can specify the length in the format string. So it should be

```
  char arr[5];
  scanf("%4s",arr);
```

Personally I would use [`fgets()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3.html) over `scanf()`:

```
fgets(arr, sizeof arr, stdin);
```

and manipulate it later using [`sscanf()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) (such as removing the trailing newline, if present; reading one X number of characters from it etc).

`fgets()` + `sscanf()` is better as it doesn't have the typical problems associated with scanf(), such as:
1) buffer overflow
2) Not clearing the input buffer etc

See: [Why does everyone say not to use scanf? What should I use instead?](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("%s",arr);
```

This prints a null terminated array. So it prints characters until it reaches '\0' character. If `arr[3] != '\0'` it will print more than you intended.

If you want to just print 4 characters it is probably better to print them seperately.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
{
    printf("%c", arr[i]);
}
```

Comment: You are ignoring the fact that his code is invoking undefined behaviour by writing more into the array then is allocated to it. If you only print 4 chars thats ok and all, but won't save the guy from getting a segfault on his scanf sometime.

Answer (score 0):

you can use fgets() to scan a variable number of chars.  Just do

```
char buffer[100];
fgets(buffer, 4, stdin);
```

and you will read only four characters, followed by a `\n` (case the line has less of three characters and one `\0` at the end signalling the end of string.

the space allocated for the buffer is normally the amount passed as the second parameter, but no need to do that.  Normally, `fscanf(3)` is called
to fill one complete line of input this way:

```
char line[1024];
while (fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin) != NULL) { /* bla, bla, bla... */
```

but there's no need to proceed this way.  You can use it to scan for only four chars with `fscan(buffer, 4, stdin);`

## Note

Take into account that `fgets(3)` finishes input when it encounters an end of line (`\n` char, `scanf(3)` skips spaces and doesn't include trailing blanks also) if it happens to be before reaching the number you pass.   If you want to read **exactly** that number of chars, you'll have to use `fread(3)` or `read(2)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

What if you need all input characters, including new lines? 
The function does the job:

```
    void fetchNextNchars(char arr[], int n) {
    char c;
    int i = 0;
    for (; i < n; i++) {
        c = getchar();
        if (c != EOF) {
            arr[i] = c;
        }
        else
            break;
    }
    arr[i] = '\0';
}
```

The array arr must be at least n + 1 characters long to hold last '\0'.

Answer (score -1):

The best way is using `getchar()`

```
void quit(const char *msg) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Program aborted");
    if (msg) fprintf(stderr, ": %s", msg);
    fprintf(stderr, ".\n");
}

    // ...
    int ch;
    ch = getchar(); if (ch == EOF) quit("error"); arr[0] = ch;
    ch = getchar(); if (ch == EOF) quit("error"); arr[1] = ch;
    ch = getchar(); if (ch == EOF) quit("error"); arr[2] = ch;
    ch = getchar(); if (ch == EOF) quit("error"); arr[3] = ch;
    // ...
```